# Alt+(letter) does not work in netbeans anymore

Tags: 15.04, netbeans

Yesterday, I have upgraded from 14.04 to 15.04 and also installed netbeans 8.1 beta (was using 8.0.1).

Now, I am unable to use any <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>(letter)</kbd> shortcut in netbeans, i.e. menubar (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for file), even if the quick-access letter is underlined (like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> for replace all).

I am not sure if this is a Ubuntu issue as it was working well in 8.0.1 in 14.04 but stopped working for both NB8.1 and NB8.0.1, or it is a Netbeans issue as the alt+letter access is working in other applications like LibreOffice ones.

**Edited:**
It seems Ubuntu issue, as other applications also have the same problem (PhpStorm v9). It seems to be related to Java based applications.

Tried to remove the alt key assignment from keyboard controls from the HUD but that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is really an Ubuntu 15.04 problem. I am using Netbeans 8.0.2 both on a 14.04 and a 15.04 desktop Ubuntu with "Eclipse" shortcut profile. In this profile <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is a shortcut for "Find in projects" feature which I use frequently. On 14.04 everything is ok, but on 15.04 it was very frustrating that I always had to use the "Edit" menu with mouse. Finally the acceptable workaround was that I changed that shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> which had not been used for other thing before.